# How to prove a matrix property?

Tags: matrices

Let $$A=\begin {bmatrix}
                    1 & 3 &  1\\
                    1 & 1 & -2\\
                    1 & 2 & -1\\
                   \end{bmatrix}
                  $$

I  need to demonstrate this relation:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, A^n \neq I_3$$
where $I_3$=identity matrix.

Comment: it helps to know that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A.$

Answer (score 2):

If you have seen eigenvalues, you know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, 
$\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. But all eigenvalues of $A$ are such that $|\lambda| \neq 1$ ($\lambda \approx 1.839$ and $\lambda \approx -0.420 \pm 0.606 i$), thus it is impossible, whatever $n$, to have $|\lambda|^n=1$ (the eigenvalue of $I_3$).

Comment: Can you provide a highschool demonstration?

Comment: @Emanuel What do you do?

Comment: You desire a "high school proof" but, at your level, beyond the definition of the product of matrices, what are the results you have seen in your lectures and that you can use ?

Comment: One idea: have you checked every coefficient of your matrix ?

Comment: newton's binom, matrix inverse, transposed matrix but i don't know if this would help. Yes i checked

Answer (score -2):

**Proof using mathematical induction:**

**The base case:** for $n=1$ we have $$A^1 = \begin {bmatrix}
                    1 & 3 &  1\\
                    1 & 1 & -2\\
                    1 & 2 & -1\\
                   \end{bmatrix}$$
So $A^1 \ne I$ is true for the base case.

**Induction hypothesis:** Assume that $A^n \ne I$ is a correct mathematical proposition and let proof that $A^{n+1} \ne I$ is also correct.
$$A^{n+1}=A^{n}\cdot A$$
According to the base case we have $A \ne I$ and according to the induction hypothesis we have $A^n \ne I$ , so $$A^n\cdot A \ne I \cdot I$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{n+1} \ne  I$$

Hence $A^{n+1} \ne  I$ is true. So $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: A^n\ne I$$

Comment: Ayoub Falah, you wrote nonsense, the implication  $A\ne B\& C\ne D \Rightarrow AB\ne CD $ is wrong of course.

Comment: @Ayoub Falah Please withdraw this: it is completely absurd.

Comment: Could you explain mathematically why should I delete it. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @bot Could you give any counterexample?

Comment: @AyoubFalah Counterexample: take $A = -I$.

Comment: @Ayoub Falah. For example $(-I)(-I)=I$.

Comment: @bot,@lastresot: but $A$ is clearly defined as $\begin {bmatrix}
                    1 & 3 &  1\\
                    1 & 1 & -2\\
                    1 & 2 & -1\\
                   \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What I meant by a counterexample that you show that $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}:A^k \cdot A=I$

Comment: @Ayoub Falah, $A=-I, k - $ odd.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @ Ayoub Falah, I mean what I say, but what  do you mean asking an axample $\exists k\in \mathbb N: A^k\cdot A= I$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39555/discussion-between-bot-and-ayoub-falah).